# Reading order of Stephen Baxter's Xeelee Sequence?

Tags: suggested-order

[Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeelee_Sequence) confused me more about Xeelee Sequence. Xeelee has appeared in lots of novels, short stories, Destiny's Children series etc. How should I read Xeelee Sequence?

I am unable to consider even publication order because I don't even have list of all works (with publication year) at unit level. Short Stories have been collected in certain books.

Also, is there any officially suggested order?

Answer (score 2):

I highly suggest to read the Xeelee Sequence in Publication-Order.

### Reading-order:

Raft, Timelike Infinity, Flux, Ring, Vacuum Diagrams, Reality Dust, Riding the Rock, Mayflower 2, Coalescent, Exultant, Transcendent, Resplendent, Starfall, Gravity Dreams, Endurance.

### Reason:

The Xeelee Sequence is a very conceptual focused work which means that Mr. Baxter developes new and strange concepts that perfectly fit together when reading the books in the way I suggested above. A reading-order using [Baxters Timeline](http://www.stephen-baxter.com/articles.html#xeelee) realy doesn't make that much sense, because temporal manipulation using dozens of various tools of time-travel is one of the core-themes of this gigantic story-arc.

Comment: What about different essays?

Comment: What do you mean with essays ? There are novels, novellas and short stories but no other material.

Comment: I meant short stories.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to read even the short-fiction in Publication-order. It has some costs (because story-arcs get divided) but it has some immense advantages too.

As I said Baxter strongly focuses on cosmological and quantum-mechanical concepts and less on stories or characters. The best way to follow the Sequence is when you read it from a "conceptual" point of view instead a "chronological" one.

Example: The short-story "Reality Dust" is set at 5.000 A.D. but it doesn't make sense to read it before, say, "Secret History" (4.000.000 A.D.) because it even if the second story is set millions of years "after" the first (but this too is highly questionable because time travel and its influence is one of the main themes).

On Wikipedia you can find that date of publication even for short-stories collected in [Vacuum Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_Diagrams) and [Resplendent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resplendent)

Answer (score 1):

Raft, Timelike Infinity, Flux, Ring, Vacuum Diagrams, Coalescent, Exultant, Transcendent, Resplendent, Starfall, Gravity Dreams, Endurance.

Reality Dust, Riding the Rock and Mayflower 2 are in Resplendent.

Comment: Any reason why this might be a good reading order for the OP?